# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics, nuxt.js, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to integrate Enhanced Ecommerce into my page (Google Analytics seems to work). The problem is - in browser console I get debug messages without errors, but on Google Analytics page I can see nothing.

So, it looks like this:

[image]

This code I just copied from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-actions):

```
  this.$ga.ecommerce.addProduct({
    'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
    'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
    'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
    'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
    'variant': 'Black',               // Product variant (string).
    'position': 1,                    // Product position (number).
    'dimension1': 'Member'            // Custom dimension (string).
  });
  this.$ga.ecommerce.setAction('click', {
    'list': 'Search Results'
  });
```

And on Google Analytics page there is nothing about this. Literally nothing except users online and pages they visit, but nothing about Enhanced Ecommerce

[image]

Somewhere on Stack Overflow I saw that on page must be only one action, I tried and it didn't work.
In any case, here is configuration of `@nuxtjs/google-analytics`:

```
const testingAnalytics = true;

module.exports = {
    modules: [
     '@nuxtjs/google-analytics',
    ],
      googleAnalytics: {
    id: process.env.GA_ID,
    dev: testingAnalytics ? true : process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    debug: testingAnalytics
      ? {
        enabled: true,
        sendHitTask: true
      }
      : {},
    ecommerce: {
      enabled: true,
      enhanced: true
    }
  },
}
```

If somebody knows, how to fix that and how to make things work, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, probably everything works properly and you can make sure clicking this button to get new report:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It takes between 24 - 48 hours for data to show up in the standard reports on Google analytics website.

If you check the real time reports you should see the hit coming in.

Realtime reports GA4

[image]

Realtime reports UA

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's true, yesterday I was trying to do that, but only today is able to see data. Could you please tell where can I find real time reports? I mean in `Realtime - Events` I can only find basic events like `event`, `time`, `page` and `set`

Comment: Realtime reports are very limited there is not much there.

Comment: This is what I am talking about, so, are there other ways to make sure that my code works correctly?

Comment: You should see a hit coming in but that's about all your going to get.